# Is it possible to make Siri to suggest add event to My App instead of default Calendar app?

Tags: ios, swift, siri, ekeventstore

I watched this video https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/243/ and I understand that My App can create and donate interactions to Siri, so that then Siri can suggest those in calendar, maps, etc. But what I am trying to achieve is a "reverse donation" i.e. when Siri finds an event in email it would suggest to add to My App instead of default Calendar app.

[image: Siri Found an Event]

If I get it right, those events found by Siri are stored in some kind of internal calendar called "Found in Natural Language" so perhaps I could do something like this?

```
let eventStore = EKEventStore()
var fetchedEvents = [EKEvent]()
        
let startDate = Date()
let endDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 30, to: Date())!
        
let predicate = eventStore.predicateForEvents(withStart: startDate, end: endDate, calendars: ["Found in Natural Language"] )
fetchedEvents = eventStore.events(matching: predicate)
```

But of course it is not just a string there, I probably need to supply actual `EKCalendar` object there, but how to do that? Is that "Found in Natural Language" calendar accessible at all?